# POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python

I am trying to convert working Python 2.7 code into Python 3 code and I am receiving a below error. Please advise.

python 2.7

```
import sys, urllib2, json, tower_cli, os, datetime, base64
req = urllib2.Request(url = 'http://test/api/v2/job_templates/23/launch/')
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('app-splunkansiblenp', 'yCXIxn0#grkuVsL$RTI9!')).replace('\n', '')
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print "Response code was: %d" % response.getcode()
```

## used python convertor tool to convert to 3.0

Python 3

```
import sys, urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse, json, tower_cli, os, datetime, base64
req = urllib2.Request(url = 'http://test/api/v2/job_templates/23/launch/')
base64string = base64.encodestring(('%s:%s' % ('app-splunkansiblenp', 'yCXIxn0#grkuVsL$RTI9!')).encode()).decode().strip()
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print("Response code was: %d" % response.getcode())
```

I can connect to ansible url using above code successfully in command prompt, but when Splunk using this using above code to connect to ansible is failing with below error. Please advise.

```
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - Traceback (most recent call last):
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/alert_ansible_tower/bin/tower_api.py", line 126, in <module>
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - main(payload)
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/alert_ansible_tower/bin/tower_api.py", line 112, in main
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - tower_launch(hostname,username,password,job_id,extra_vars)
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/alert_ansible_tower/bin/tower_api.py", line 70, in tower_launch
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - req = meth(req)
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - File "/opt/splunk/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1280, in do_request_
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - raise TypeError(msg)
 ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
 INFO sendmodalert - action=tower_api - Alert action script completed in duration=333 ms with exit code=1
```

Comment: your python3 code is not a runnable example. For example you reference urllib2.Request but dont declare that is an import in your python3 code so where is that defined

Comment: Sorry for the typo, below is the code     

    import sys, urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse, json, tower_cli, os, datetime, base64
 req = urllib.request.Request(url = 'http://test/api/v2/job_templates/23/launch/')
    base64string = base64.encodestring(('%s:%s' % ('app-splunkansiblenp', 'yCXIxn0#grkuVsL$RTI9!')).encode()).decode().strip()
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    print("Response code was: %d" % response.getcode())

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to troubleshoot why its failing with below error.  ERROR sendmodalert - action=tower_api STDERR - TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.